# WEKA - Multi Class Classification - Can't find class called: weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.RegSMOImproved

Tags: java, machine-learning, svm, weka

I'm trying to train a `MultiClassClassifier`model in Weka with the base algorithm set to `weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.RegSMOImproved` class, with the following options:

```
    MultiClassClassifier cModel = new MultiClassClassifier();
    String options[] = {
            "weka.classifiers.meta.MultiClassClassifier",
            "-M","0",
            "-R","2.0",
            "-S","1",
            "-W","weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.RegSMOImproved",
            "-P","1.0e-12",
            "-L","1.0e-3",
            "-W","1"
    };
    try {
        cModel.setOptions(options);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I run my code I get the following error:

```
java.lang.Exception: Can't find class called: weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.RegSMOImproved
    at weka.core.Utils.forName(Utils.java:1073)
    at weka.classifiers.AbstractClassifier.forName(AbstractClassifier.java:90)
    at weka.classifiers.SingleClassifierEnhancer.setOptions(SingleClassifierEnhancer.java:108)
    at weka.classifiers.RandomizableSingleClassifierEnhancer.setOptions(RandomizableSingleClassifierEnhancer.java:93)
    at weka.classifiers.meta.MultiClassClassifier.setOptions(MultiClassClassifier.java:802)
    at myApp.Main.trainMultiClassClassifier(Main.java:983)
    at myApp.Main.createSets(Main.java:903)
    at myApp.Main.main(Main.java:387)
```

**What is the correct class path for use of RegSMOImproved algorithm if not** `weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.RegSMOImproved`**?**

**Am I missing something else here, an additional setting perhaps, or some kind of a parent class?**

I'm using Weka developer-branch from [here](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/~ml/weka/snapshots/weka_snapshots.html). If there is anything I left out unintentionally please let me know and I'll make an edit asap.

Thank You in advance.

**EDIT 1:**

I'm trying to accomplish multi class classification where I would train my model/models as one class vs. the rest. My data is balanced (100 samples per class). This is what I've found so far:

http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/meta-multi-class-classifier-with-the-option-smo-td26548.html

**EDIT 2:**

So I've changed my options object to:

```
    String options[] = {
            "-M","0",
            "-R","2.0",
            "-S","1",
            "-W","weka.classifiers.functions.SMO",
            "--",
            "-C","1",
            "-L","0.001",
            "-P","1.0e-12",
            "-M",
            "-N", "0",
            "-V","-1",
            "-W","1",
            "-K", "weka.classifiers.functions.supportVector.PolyKernel -C 250007 -E 1.0"
    };
```

This seems to go through `setOptions()`, so I've clearly mixed the two SMO classes from `supportVector` and `functions` packages. I've also read that I need to set the `-M` and `-V` properties for SMO in order for my MultiClassClassifier to work correctly. So I've turned on "fitting calibration models to SVM outputs" with the -M property and I've set the number of folds for cross validation to -1 (default) with the -V property.

I assume the number of folds property for cross validation has to be set for testing purposes. Will have to check out posts on cross validation from this point.

Thank You again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) you probably shouldn't be using the developer branch unless you have a specific need. For all we know they are moving stuff around and its potentially broken

B) RegSMOImproved is for **Reg**ression , not classification. So some of your issues could be that miss match between the MultiClassClassifier and a regression algorithm.

Comment: My miss match between supportVector and functions packages was the issue in my code. I have updated my post with the working options object. Now I need to check out weka cross validation settings so I can get my  multi class classifier to work correctly. Thank you again.